# CakePhp 3 - How to order by SUM in contain result

Tags: php, database, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

I am working on CakePhp 3 project and i need to sort comments on articles by SUM of votes on each comment.

Models:

- Articles
- ArticlesComments
- ArticlesCommentsVotes
- Users

User is associated to each model. ArticlesComments has article id. ArticlesCommentsVotes has comment_id and user_id.

What I need:

- Total No. of positive comments
- Total No. of negative comments
- Sort by No. Positive comments
- Sort by No. of Negative comments

Somehow, I managed to get Total no. of positive and Negative comments, but CakePhp would not allow me to sort by No. of comments.

Here is my query:

```
$article = $this->Articles->get($id, [
            'contain' => [
                'Categories',
                'Clusters',
                'Tags',
                'ArticlesSteps',
                'PositiveVotes'    => function ($a){
                    return $a->select(['PositiveVotes.article_id', 'votes' => 'COUNT(*)']);
                },
                'NegativeVotes'    => function ($a){
                    return $a->select(['NegativeVotes.article_id', 'votes' => 'COUNT(*)']);
                },
                'ArticlesComments' => function ($q){
                    return $q->contain([
                        'Users'                 => function ($q){
                            return $q->select(['username']);
                        },
                        'CommentVote'           => function ($q){
                            return $q->select(['vote']);
                        },
                        'CommentsPositiveVotes' => function ($q){
                            return $q->select(['CommentsPositiveVotes.comment_id', 'positive' => 'SUM(vote)'])->group('comment_id');
                        },
                        'CommentsNegativeVotes' => function ($a){
                            return $a->select(['CommentsNegativeVotes.comment_id', 'CommentsNegativeVotes.user_id']);
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            ]
        ]);
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix it. I need to use left Join for it. Here is my updated code:

```
       // Search comments
        $comments = $this->ArticlesComments->find()->where([
            'ArticlesComments.article_id' => $articleId,
        ])->contain([
            'CommentVote' => function ($q){
                return $q->select(['vote']);
            },
            'Users'       => function ($q){
                return $q->select(['username']);
            },
        ]);

        // Left Join with ArticlesComments
        $comments
            ->leftJoin(
                ['ArticlesCommentsVotes' => 'articles_comments_votes'],
                ['ArticlesComments.id = ArticlesCommentsVotes.comment_id']
            );


        // Case
        $ratingCases = $comments->newExpr()->addCase([
            $comments->newExpr()->add(['ArticlesCommentsVotes.vote' => '1']),
            $comments->newExpr()->add(['ArticlesCommentsVotes.vote' => '0'])
        ], [1, - 1, 0], ['integer','integer','integer']);

        // Calculate rating and sort
        $comments->select(['rating' => $comments->func()->sum($ratingCases)])
                 ->group('ArticlesCommentsVotes.comment_id')->order($sortBy . ' ' . $sortOrder)->autoFields(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can't sort on a query result. But in your case, it would make sense using somehting called "CounterCache".

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply